# How to rewrite url containing plus and special chracters?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

We've got some incoming URLs that needs to be redirected, but we are having trouble with URLs that contains pluses (+).

For example any incoming URL must be redirected to the Homepage of the new site:

> /eng/news/2005+01+01.htm

Should be redirected to to the home page of the new site

> /en/

Using UrlRewriter.net we've set up a rule which works with 'normal' URLs but does not work for the above

```
<redirect url="~/eng/(.+)" to="/en/index.aspx" />
```

However it works fine if i change the incoming URL to

> /eng/news/2005-01-01.htm

What's the problem and can anyone help?

Comment: Why is there a `~` at the start?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `UrlRewriter.net`, and I'm not sure which regex syntax it uses. I give some hint based on Perl regex.

1. what is the `~` at the beginning? Perhaps you mean `^`, i.e. beginning of the string.
2. `(.+)` matches any character repeated one or more time; it does not match the `+` sign as you want

This is one way to write a (Perl) regex matching URLs starting with the string `/eng/` and containg a `+` sign:

`^\/eng\/.*\+.*`

I hope this helps.

Comment: UrlRewriter.net uses the .NET regex syntax - where `.` *does* include the `+` character - just like every other regex flavour I've experienced.

Comment: Also, even if dot somehow doesn't include plus, using `.*\+.*` wont work when he has multiple `+` characters (as in example). Something like `[^\n]*` would be simpler

Comment: @Peter Boughton: why do you say it does not work? I think it does: If I do `perl -pi -e 'if (/^\/eng\/.*\+.*/) { print "yes\n"; } else { print "no\n"; }'`, and I give `/eng/news/2005+01+01.htm` as input, I get `yes` as output.

Comment: It works because the `.` *does* include the `+` character. If you change `.` to `[^+]` in your example expression, it wont work (because there are two `+` characters, and only one tested for/allowed).

Comment: The only difference between `.*` and `.*\+.*` is that the latter *must* include at least one `+` whilst the former can include anything (except newlines, which shouldn't apply with URL rewriting anyway).

Comment: @Peter Boughton: I see your point, and you're right. However, I understood that the requirement was to match a URLs including at least one `+`, and that's why I wrote the regex in that way.

Comment: We'll need to wait for the OP to return and clarify that then.